# subclass uitextview and calculate size with attributed string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am subclassing a UITextView and trying to calculate it's size before hand (for a cell) such that I can correctly set the cells height. I am trying to use `boundingRectWithSize` but unfortunately it is not returning the expected results. See below:

(I am on iOS 8)

```
@interface SCTextView : UITextView
@end

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text {
  [super setText:text];

  self.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text attributes:[SCColorScheme defaultScheme].defaultTextAttributes];
}

+(CGSize)measureWithAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString andWidthConstraint:(CGFloat)maxWidth {
    SCTextView *hello = [[self alloc] init];
    hello.text = attrString.string;
    CGRect f = hello.frame;
    f.size.width = maxWidth;
    hello.frame = f;
    [hello sizeToFit];

    // hello.frame.size.height returns 34.00
    return hello.frame.size;

    NSLog(@"are they the same?: %@", [hello.attributedText isEqualToAttributedString:attrString] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    // Returns true

    // boundingRect.size.height returns 17.234
    CGSize boundRectSize =  [attrString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                           context:nil
                                           ].size;

    // Returns false.
    NSLog(@"these are not: %@", [boundingRectSize.width isEqual:hello.frame.size.width] ? @"YES" : @"NO"]);
}
```

Comment: FYI - no code after the call to `return` will be executed.

Comment: Yes, that was simply to illustrate the result of each line. They are commented out.

Comment: I think this is because UITextView has a default UIEdgeInsets {8, 0, 8, 0}.